# Why is a fermented sugar wash white and opaque?

Tags: fermentation, sugar, clarity, color

For various reasons I have done a series of test fermentations with various types of ginger powder in the mix. The control was a solution of sugar in water (OG 1.040) with some tartaric acid, boiled for 20 minutes, then cooled, aerated and fermented with a bit of yeast nutrient and some rebate white wine yeast. Other versions were the same but had additions of various ginger powders added but were otherwise the same.

The versions with the ginger powder came out clear and lightly straw colored. Obviously the ginger powder has acted as a flocculant somehow, which I did not expect, but okay. However, the control came out white (not yellowish) and opaque, almost like a suspension of milk in water. The control tasted pretty much as expected (a fermented sugar wash) and so did the others with the addition of hot ginger flavors from the powder.

The yeast had settled out (there was a clear deposit at the bottom) and the solution is far too light (white) in color to make me think "yeast". So it's got to be something else that makes this control solution white and opaque.

But what could that be?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing it’s the tartaric acid has an ion charge that holds it in suspension and that something about the ginger root was the flocculant that bound with it allowed it to drop out.

Comment: That ginger root powder acted as a flocculant was clear. but your suggestion about ion charge is well taken. Thank you!